# how to fix pop from empty list error when using keras.layers.Dot in GPU mode

Tags: keras, deep-learning, gpu, amazon-sagemaker, mxnet

I'm trying to train a simple model with embeddings on Sagemaker, using Mxnet backhand and aiming to run across multiple GPUs.

The line below is causing an error:

```
   preprod = keras.layers.Dot(axes=1, normalize=False)([bet_vec, user_vec])
```

Whenever I use keras.layers.Dot I get the following error msg:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/backend/mxnet_backend.py", line 2292, in squeeze
    assert shape.pop(axis) == 1, 'Can only squeeze size 1 dimension'
IndexError: pop from empty list

The code runs fine locally but it does not work using Mxnet/GPUs...

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Thank you :-)

Comment: Can you confirm the shapes of `bet_vec` and `user_vec`? It looks like `squeeze` is being called on an array with no shape!

Comment: Could it be that `Dot` need two arguments, and you're passing one? So the second argument would be the empty one.